# MySQL - wrong symbol causes string silently not saving

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

MySQL 5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

The string containing turkish symbols
/* sayfa başlığı */
not saving to the column

```
body longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
```

Column remains empty when other columns of the same INSERT have data. No error displayed (PHP, error reporting enabled).

The problem string was recieved as css file with encoding
text/css without charset and Opera browser displays it correctly. The attempt to serve this css with
text/css;charset=UTF-8 outputs wrong symbols.

Is any possibility to suppress wrong symbols to save the string? I don't like base64- or other encoding since I'd like to edit field in Adminer/phpMyAdmin?

```
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4', 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci');
```

was issued and there are no problems with Unicode strings.

Comment: How are you writing the data? Does the driver being used throw errors? Is the driver being used with error reporting enabled?

Comment: I use ZebraDatabase (You can goole it) and another errors are displayed

Comment: Is `another errors are displayed` a typo? If not please provide errors, if so have you used the error reporting for Zebra, https://stefangabos.github.io/Zebra_Database/Zebra_Database/Zebra_Database.html#methoderror? It would improve the question if you added the code.

Comment: None of [those characters](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=sayfa+ba%C5%9Fl%C4%B1%C4%9F%C4%B1) require more than 2 bytes so even good old 3-byte `utf8` should suffice. You're probably failing to use UTF-8 in some step of your workflow and don't have a SQL mode that handles that as error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: user3783243 I meant that if I make an error it would be displayed. Like "Incorrect datetime value: 'qwerty' for column 'updated_at' at row 1"; $db->error() is empty after insertion

Comment: "wrong symbols" --Let's see the symbols, it may give a useful clue.  Also, can you dump the source in hex?

Comment: Based on the "wrong symbols", this may provide an answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored